# how do i settle this overloading java

Tags: java

how to calculate 2 number integer and float by using overloading in java

```
class Darab{
    float HasilDarab(int a ,int b){
        int total;
        total= a*b;
        return total;
    }
    float HasilDarab(float a ,float b){
        float total;
        total=a*b;
        return total;
    }
}

class MethodOverloading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float hasildarab1,hasildarab2,a=5,b=6;

        Darab obj1=new Darab();
        hasildarab1=obj1.HasilDarab(a,b);
        hasildarab2=obj1.HasilDarab(a,b);

        System.out.println("Hasil darab dalam interger"+hasildarab1);
        System.out.println("Hasil darab dalam float"+hasildarab2);

    }
}
```

this is my code but i still get both of them is float

Comment: You could probably make your life a lot easier by just giving the functions different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your `a` and `b` variables as `float`, so Java selects the method that has parameters of type `float`, because, in addition to a  method name, Java uses parameter types to differentiate between methods. See more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Try to rewrite your code as:

```java
float hasildarab1, a = 5, b = 6;
int hasildarab2, c = 5, d = 6;

Darab obj1 = new Darab();
hasildarab1 = obj1.HasilDarab(a, b);
hasildarab2 = obj1.HasilDarab(c, d);
```

UPD: Also, as Dawood ibn Kareem correctly mentioned in the comment, you need to change the return type of the first `HasilDarab` method to `int`.

Comment: Both versions of `HasilDarab` return `float`, so `hasildarab2` needs to be `float`.

Comment: you can cast `a` and `b` to int, there is no need to use a different vars.